# Setting up android phone with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have been developing a project app to learn about android, I can upload my app to my htc desire on my desktop using linux ubuntu and eclipse, I have the same setup on my laptop but I cannot upload apps to my phone.  When I try to install the app to the phone it shows up in avd manager as ??????? ????? Unknown, I've googled this and the general advice is to setup a script which I have tried but I get an error message saying path does not exist, when I try to kill the adb server it says no such command even though I am in root and can see the adb file in the sdk folder, I am completely lost here anyone help with this.....

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you get it to work on your desktop but you can't get it on your laptop? Were you the one to set it up on your desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are running Linux on your laptop. Try these steps as your normal user:

If you haven't already set up the udev rules for your device, follow these steps:

```
1. sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
2. copy/paste this line into that rules file: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
3. sudo service udev restart
```

Then, restart the adb server:

```
cd </path/to/your>/android-sdk/tools directory
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb start-server
```

If it's not there already, you can add the /path/to/your/android-sdk/tools to your $PATH variable so you don't need to cd to the directory and also won't have to use the ./ to use the adb command.

You may need to unplug/replug the USB cable to your phone after you do all this.

Comment: Thank you this worked although I couldn't create the udev rules restarting the adb server worked a treat, I had done this before but all the tutorials did not include the ./ in front of adb