# ADB Crashing in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

This question relates to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573019/adb-crashes-when-device-attached-with-eclipse), however that thread has no answers so this it not technically a duplicate.

I've got ADB 1.0.26 running on my Windows 7 x64 and Eclipse SDK 3.6.2 with ADT 10.0.1 SDK tools r10, and I've got all the Android SDK versions installed.

When I connect my phone to the computer in debug mode, and type `adb devices` into the command prompt, my phone shows up. It's an Inspire 4G. I can `adb shell` into the device and `ls`, so I'm assuming that the adb/driver/phone part of the chain is working properly.

Now, if I connect my phone and go into Eclipse, I get:

> [2011-03-28 17:46:33 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> [2011-03-28 17:46:34 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
>
> [2011-03-28 17:46:36 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 2

[...]

> [2011-03-28 17:47:53 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 10
>
> [2011-03-28 17:46:54 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 11
>
> [2011-03-28 17:47:00 - adb]
>
> [2011-03-28 17:47:00 - adb]This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual     way.
>
> [2011-03-28 17:47:00 - adb]Please contact the application's support team for more information.
>
> [2011-03-28 17:47:04 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> [2011-03-28 17:47:05 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
>
> [2011-03-28 17:47:07 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 2

etc, etc... This loops forever.
It doesn't matter if I start Eclipse and then connect the phone, or if I connect the phone and then start Eclipse.

I don't think it should matter, but my phone is an Inspire 4G which is rooted and running Revolution 4G 3.2

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573019/adb-crashes-when-device-attached-with-eclipse) a programming question? how about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994062/eclipse-adb-error-message-in-vista-failed-to-parse-the-output-of-adb-version), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133814/phone-doesnt-show-up-in-eclipse-eventhough-adb-is-working), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912548/android-adb-unable-to-open-sync-connection), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926648/setting-up-android-phone-with-eclipse)?????

Comment: 5 wrongs don't make a right :)

Comment: Why is it wrong? Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - Point #4: "software tools commonly used by programmers". There are LOADS of questions about Visual Studio, QT, compilers, and apparently also Android which are technical/troubleshooting questions rather than coding-specific questions. If you don't like it, then you can suggest an amendment to the StackOverflow rules to the admins. =)

Comment: Respect trojanfoe for admitting defeat in an Internet argument! You must be the first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this patched adb version worked fine for me (HTC Desire HD):
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12141

Answer (score 1):

For this go to DDMS, Look for Devices-->View Menu-->Reset adb.

Comment: This does not help. If I reset ADB it keeps doing the same thing over and over. In DDMS I can see my phone appear and then disappear a few seconds later.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Revolution 4G ROMs installed? If so, then I had to install the no-sense patch to remove all the HTC stuff. Once I did that, ADB stopped crashing in Eclipse.

Edit - Actually it seems like it still crashes sometimes, but not as often? Still not a solution.

Comment: Yes, I'm running Revolution 4G. I have been running it since 3.2 all the way to the current 5.1.4, and it has been crashing in every version. I have pretty much given up at this stage. As you said, I think it's a ROM issue.

Comment: Have you asked Mike about this on xda?