# Errors while running a sample android app

Tags: eclipse, debugging, android

I installed eclipse in my new laptop, and also installed necessary sdks. I am just trying to run a sample android app "HelloEffects" from the list, but I am getting below errors when trying to run the app :

> [2014-07-26 20:40:28 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 225 
>   [2014-07-26 20:40:49 - adb] ADB server didn't ACK 
>  [2014-07-26
>   20:40:49 - adb] * failed to start daemon * 
>  [2014-07-26 20:40:49 -
>   ddms]
>   'C:\Users\shantanu\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server'
>   failed -- run manually if necessary 
>  [2014-07-26 20:40:49 -
>   DeviceMonitor] adb restart attempts: 215

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: did u try adb start-server (adb kill-server) from cmd line?

Comment: saw this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455553/adb-crashing-in-eclipse) , tried the same also. but i am getting error as "Adb failed to start, Make sure the plugin is properly configured".

Comment: hi eldjon, ya tried these commands also. Getting below error in cmd: 


* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *

Comment: any firewall or antivirus that may block any program to open ports?

Comment: i am using avast anti virus. but i dont think it is blocking the port. there is no change in firewall settings also. it is in default mode.

Comment: i would suggest to disable antivirus and firewall just to make sure that its not the case. it seems that 5037 port might be occupied by another program so try to kill that process also and then type the start-server/kill-server commands